# In Batman Arkham Asylum, does the game continue after the story is finished?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

I'm currently playing through this game (bit late to it, I know) and am wondering if the game will allow me to go back to previous regions and find all the collectables (Riddler Trophies, etc) after I've completed the story - or if I need to do these as I go through the game?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can freeplay after the end of the game in order to collect all the Riddler trophies and complete any challenges you may have missed.

*This answer is applicable to the PS3 version and may be applicable to the other versions as well.*

Comment: I confirm that this is applicable to the XBox 360 version too.

Comment: It's the same for PC.

Answer (score 5):

The game does not continue, it ends immediately after the last boss fight; however you can roam around as you please just before it begins.

Spoiler about how you know you're about to reach the no-turning-back point:

> When there are about 20 goons clapping and cheering for you just before the visitor's center. Once you open the door to the visitor's center, you cannot go back.

If I recall correctly there's also an auto-save just before the no-turning-back point so after finishing the game you can load it (also via "continue") and play from there - but it takes place before the final fight, so it's not a continuation.

Comment: Perhaps one of us has a patched or updated copy of the game?  I was able to reload my game and play after the end of the final boss fight.

Comment: @Steve maybe, but it's also possible we agree but just have different definitions :) if you reload the game and play, can you fight the final boss again?

Comment: No, the door to the final boss is closed but the fireworks are still going off.  You can't fight the final boss again.  ...  I know what it might be!  Are you talking about the 360 version or the PS3 version?  I'm talking about PS3.

Comment: @Steve I see what you mean... odd. In any case I'm talking about the PC version.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly